big tcp packets are sometimes truncated
everyone!
I build tcp server and tcp client to test tcp package length, and I set the limit to 64k.
When I transter small data, it is ok. But when data becomes larger(I set 60,000 bytes), sometimes it is ok, sometimes part of the data is truncated, and many '0' shows.
error picture
I am very confused about the result. Can anyone give me some advice? Thank you very much.
Below is my code, or you can see on https://github.com/Cxj2016/tcpLengthTest
1.Client:
package base

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

type TcpClient struct {
    conn *Connection
}

func NewClient() *TcpClient {
    return &TcpClient{}
}

func (t *TcpClient) Connect(address string) error {
    cn, err := net.Dial("tcp", address)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("client dial failed|err:%v\n", err)
        return err
    }
    t.conn = NewConnection(cn)
    t.conn.Run()

    return nil
}

func (t *TcpClient) Write(msg *Message) {
    t.conn.writeQ <- msg
}

2.Server
package base

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

type TcpServer struct {
    listener net.Listener
}

func NewTcpServer() *TcpServer {
    return &TcpServer{}
}

func (t *TcpServer) Listen(address string) error {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", address)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("listen failed|err:%v\n", err)
        return err
    }

    t.listener = lis
    go t.acceptConn()

    return err
}

func (t *TcpServer) acceptConn() {
    for {
        conn, err := t.listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("accept failed|err:%v\n", err)
            return
        }

        go t.handleConn(conn)
    }
}

func (t *TcpServer) handleConn(c net.Conn) {
    newConn := NewConnection(c)
    newConn.Run()
}

3.Connection
package base

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

type Connection struct {
    conn   net.Conn
    writeQ chan *Message
    writer *bufio.Writer
    reader *bufio.Reader
}

func NewConnection(conn net.Conn) *Connection {
    return &Connection{
        conn:   conn,
        writeQ: make(chan *Message, 100),
        writer: bufio.NewWriterSize(conn, 1024*64),
        reader: bufio.NewReaderSize(conn, 1024*64),
    }
}

func (c *Connection) Run() {
    go c.loopRead()
    go c.loopWrite()
}

func (c *Connection) loopRead() {
    for {
        header, err := c.reader.Peek(HeaderLength)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("peek header failed|err:%v\n", err)
            return
        }

        dataLength := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(header[0:])
        fmt.Printf("read data to read|header:%v|length:%d\n", header, dataLength)

        msgBuff := make([]byte, HeaderLength+dataLength)
        if _, err = c.reader.Read(msgBuff); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("read msg buff failed|err:%v\n", err)
            return
        }

        fmt.Printf("read total length:%d|data:%v\n", len(msgBuff), msgBuff[HeaderLength:])
    }
}

func (c *Connection) loopWrite() {
    for {
        select {
        case msg := <-c.writeQ:
            var header = make([]byte, HeaderLength) //data Length
            length := len(msg.Data)
            binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(header[0:], uint32(length))
            fmt.Printf("write header:%v|length:%d\n", header, length)
            if _, err := c.writer.Write(header); err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("write header failed|err:%v\n", err)
                return
            }

            if length > 0 {
                if _, err := c.writer.Write(msg.Data); err != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("write body failed|err:%v\n", err)
                    return
                }
            }

            if err := c.writer.Flush(); err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("flush failed|err:%v\n", err)
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

4.Other
package base

const (
    Addr         = "127.0.0.1:8998"
    HeaderLength = 4
)

type Message struct {
    Length uint32
    Data   []byte
}

5.Main Method
1> client
func main() {
    c := base.NewClient()
    if err := c.Connect(base.Addr); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("client connect failed|err:%v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    for {
        msg := &base.Message{}
        for i := 0; i < 60000; i++ {
            msg.Data = append(msg.Data, 'a')
        }
        c.Write(msg)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
    }
}

2> server
func main() {
    server := base.NewTcpServer()
    if err := server.Listen(base.Addr); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("listen failed|err:%v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    for {

    }
}


Important distinctions: you are not reading a "packet", you are reading from a stream. The message isn't "truncated", you just didn't read the entire message.

The following snippet from your code improperly attempts to use the bufio.Reader.Read API to fill a large buffer.
msgBuff := make([]byte, HeaderLength+dataLength)
if _, err = c.reader.Read(msgBuff); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("read msg buff failed|err:%v\n", err)
    return
}

The documentation of that function says this (emphasis mine):

The bytes are taken from at most one Read on the underlying Reader, hence n may be less than len(p). To read exactly len(p) bytes, use io.ReadFull(b, p).

Try altering your code to follow that advice:
import "io"
msgBuf := make([]byte, HeaderLength+dataLength)
if _, err = io.ReadFull(c.reader, msgBuf); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("read msg buff failed|err:%v\n", err)
    return
}

Note that bufio.Writer.Write doesn't have a similar issue, so your writing code looks correct.
